# Unable to publish Angular Application using GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am unable to publish my angular application using GitHub pages.

Seeing this error

```
about-me (master)*$ ngh
An error occurred!
 Error: Unspecified error (run without silent option for detail)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/gh-pages/lib/index.js:232:19
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli-ghpages/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

run `ng build --prod` for production version this will get you your files in dist folder

First get all relevant the files from the Dist Folder of your application

for me it was the css files in the assets folder main.bundle.js polyfills.bundle.js vendor.bundle.js

Then push this files in the repo which you have created.

1 -- If you want the application to run on the root directory - create a special repo with the name [yourgithubusername].github.io and opush these files in the master branch

2 -- Where as if you want to create these page in the sub directory of in a different brach other than than the root , create a branch gh-pages and push these files in that branch.

In both the cases the way we access these deployed pages will be different .

For the First Case it will be https://[yourgithubusername].github.io and for the second case it will be [yourgithubusername].github.io/[Repo name].

If Suppose you want to deploy it using the sefcond case make sure to change the base url pf the index.html file in the dist as all the route mappings depend on the path you give and it should be set to [/branchname].

Link to this page

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/Deployment

Comment: Thanks for your response, @rahul. Could you please elaborate how to do it. I am a beginner to Github pages and Angular.

Comment: @NikhilB is the problem sorted for you

Comment: Hello @Rahul, I was able to sort the problem, but how to deploy the angular app at https://<USERNAME>.github.io ?